# How to search in existing contracts? e.g. find the Account contract in existing Accounts by using accountid

Tags: daml

What should I do to find an existing contracts?

e.g. I have a template which create Account contract. Before creating the contract, I need to search the existing contracts to make sure the account id is not duplicated.

Comment: It sounds likely that a soon to be released feature called "contract keys" might be brought to bear on this problem. With this you'll be able to efficiently determine if there is an existing contract associated with a candidate account ID. Please keep an eye out on our blogs in the coming week for more information about that. In the meantime, I hope/expect that others will jump in your question and offer shorter term solutions!

Comment: It seems that the latest DAML allows you to create template with keys. And those keys can be used in the functions such as fetch or lookup. I will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Shayne Fletcher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10148312/shayne-fletcher) points out, DAML recently gained a feature called "Contract Keys" which addresses the specific issue you are trying to solve. You make use of this feature by declaring a `key` on a `template` together with a set of `maintainers`, who ensure the uniqueness constraint in that key and validate any lookups.

```
template Account
  with
    issuer: Party
    owner: Party
    accountNo: Text
  where
    signatory issuer
    observer owner

    key (issuer, accountNo) : (Party, Text)
    maintainer issuer
```

The above specifies that the tuple `(issuer, accountNo)` is the "primary key" of this type of contract and that the `issuer` of an account is responsible for maintaining the index for accounts issued by them.

You now have two functions at your disposal: `fetchByKey` and `lookupByKey`. Both take a tuple `(Party, Text)`. `fetchByKey` returns a tuple `(ContractId Account, Account)` and aborts the transaction if the key can't be found. `lookupByKey` returns an `Optional (ContractId Account)`, with the additional subtlety, that the use of `lookupByKey` must be authorised by the `issuer`.

More generally, though, queries tend to be done off-ledger, in the integration layer of the application. If, for example, you wanted to check that a given `owner` doesn't hold more than 10 account already, you would typically do that by maintaining a mirror of the active `Account` templates in a queryable database of your choice and querying that before submitting your transaction.

You can have a look at this [example](https://github.com/digital-asset/ex-models/tree/master/mongoDB_ODS), which maintains all active contracts in a MongoDB.

Comment: I wanted to maintains all the active contracts in a DB as well. Would you mind sharing your code. I am not able to make it work. I implemented a BOT.